# How does one install a new dialogue in Bluesky Statistics v.10

Tags: r, installation, statistics, dialog

In the pdf "Installing new dialog(s) in BlueSky Statistics" one is instructed to open "BlueSky Statistics dialog installer" (‘Tools -> Dialog Installer’). But in v.10 there doesn't seem to be a Tools menu.
On the BlueSky  website I *can* find DialogueDesigner. However, once I've created a dialogue to test...how do I install it?
Thank you,
Peter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, v10 does not support this feature anymore.
So you may want to use v7.x for it.
(if you miss out some feature in v7.x, it is possible to add additional R packages and run some R codes directly as well)